# SELECT using Reverse-LIKE from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sqlite

I want to store data with wildcard char like,

- "I am % , want your help"
- "Thanks %"

And later on, I want to retrieve data from it using strings which are like,

- "I am Pruthvesh Pipaliya , want your help"
- "Thanks Mr. X"

Is there any way to do this in SQLite?
If not in SQLite, is their any way to do using any other database or any other technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LIKE operator wants a string on the left side and a pattern on the right side. So give it that:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 'Thanks Mr. X' LIKE MyColumn;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the replacement in your application layer, not the data layer. You have tagged this question with asp.net and sql, so something like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE messageId = 4
```

To get the message template

I would also change your wildcards to .net string replace formats. So, for example, store in the database as:

```
"Thanks {0}."
```

instead of

```
"Thanks %."
```

and then in the application something like:

```
var salutationTemplate = >> record from db <<
var salutation = string.Format(salutationTemplate, "Name to replace");
```

This will replace the {0} (and you can also do {1}, {2}, etc) with the values that come after.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK u have to store the complete record(column) in the database. Then u can use java(for example) to create prepared statements like below.

```
String query = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ..."+ //
"AND UPPER(INTRODUCTION) LIKE UPPER(?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, "I am %, want your help%");
```

Also if you are trying to create a generic email then you can use template mechanism.